# value of argument for operator new[] in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Consider the following code which contains a class with overloads for `new` and  `new[]`:

```
#include <iostream>


class my_class  {
public:
    my_class() {};
    my_class(const my_class& rhs) {};
    ~my_class() {};

//the constructor also as applicable.
    void * operator new(size_t sz); 
    void * operator new[](size_t sz);
    void operator delete(void * ptr);
    void operator delete[](void * ptr);
private:    
};

void * my_class::operator new(size_t sz)
{
    std::cout << "at operator new, sz is: " << sz << std::endl;
}

void * my_class::operator new[](size_t sz)
{
    std::cout << "at operator new[], sz is: " << sz << std::endl;
}

void my_class::operator delete(void * ptr)
{
    std::cout << "at operator delete, ptr is: " << ptr << std::endl;
}

void my_class::operator delete[](void * ptr)
{
    std::cout << "at operator delete[], ptr is: " << ptr << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    my_class * ptr = new my_class;
    my_class * arr_ptr = new my_class[1];
    return 0;
}
```

Running this in the terminal (Cygwin) I see:

```
at operator new, sz is: 1
at operator new[], sz is: 9
```

Why is `sz == 9` when `operator new[]` is called ? Who sets it? What does it depend on (eg. page size?)?

Comment: Fist of all, your `new` should actually return something (and not `NULL`). Until then this has UB.

Comment: agreed,  this is not meant to be a proper implementation, just an investigation on how size_t sz is computed

Answer (score 2):

A new-*expression*, like `new my_class` does more than call `operator new`; `operator new` only allocates memory, and its parameter is the size of the memory it is supposed to allocate.

The parameter `sz` of `operator new` is 1 because that's the smallest possible instance; `sizeof(my_class)` is 1.

The parameter `sz` of `operator new[]` is 9 because that is how much memory the `new[]`-expression (`new my_class[1]`) requires for allocating an array of 1 instance of size 1.

The "extra" 8 is for keeping track of things like how many elements there are.
The size of the "extra" memory is implementation-dependent.

Comment: Thanks for this, I changed the array size and I can confirm what you say is true.

Answer (score 1):

The [runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900549/what-is-runtime) "sets" the value when you invoke the operator `new`. There is an implicit `sizeof` passed around. It is the same situation as with invoking member functions without implicitly passing around the pointer to the current instance `this`.

In your case you have a class with no members, so theoretically its size should be zero, however C++ allocates one byte (due to the fact that the objects must at least be addressable). That's why the result of the first allocation is 1 (assuming you fix your operators `new/new[]` to return something, until then you have UB). The second allocation returns 9 due to how C++ represents dynamic arrays, it puts some header somewhere (implementation defined) so it recognizes it is an array (so when invoking `operator delete[]`, the latter behaves properly) and perhaps due to padding.

Comment: So as I am using Windows, would it be the windows runtime that determine this ?

Comment: By runtime I mean the standard library shared libraries that are used when your program runs, in combination with the operating system. I am not absolutely sure how this works internally, probably everything translates to some OS system calls, in which the `sizeof` is passed around. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900549/what-is-runtime for a bit of details about runtime.