# Is C runtime an essential for any other programs like lua, haskell, java, etc...?

Tags: c, runtime

From the QnA for what a runtime is : [What is "runtime"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900549/what-is-runtime)

I understood about runtime a little.
To make my understanding more robust, I'd like to ask new question.

Is C runtime an essential for any other programs like lua, haskell, java, etc... ?

I know C library implements not only standard C api but also system call wrappers also.

And I know lua runtime is no different than just a C program. This means lua runtime is based on C runtime.

So I guess any other language would be in the same situation. <del>Because it is only C rumtime which can call system calls.</del>

I considered for linux but I guess Windows and other Unix implementations must be same.

Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily.

All programs written in C make use of the C runtime environment, be it the standard library, the stuff happening before the `main` function, or else.

If a compiler/interpreter/virtual machine is written in C, yes, it **does** make use of the C runtime.
OTOH, if it isn't, it does **not**.

**Note** that you have to go up the whole "compiler/interpreter/virtual machine chain."
A Python interpreter written in Haskell might still indirectly rely on the C runtime environment if the Haskell interpreter has been written in C.

> [...] it is only C rumtime [sic] which can call system calls.

No. The C runtime provides wrappers around some system calls. You can write programs in pure assembly **making use of system calls** and not rely on the C runtime library at all.

Comment: Thank you very much I think I can understand.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can bypass the crt with -nodefaultlib on msvc