# C99 Variable length arrays in GDB

Tags: c, gdb, c99

At this simple C99-Code:

```
int main(void){
  int a[3][3] = {1};
  int m = 3;
  int x;
  int b[m][m];
  x = sizeof(b);
  b[0][0] = -1;
  return 0;
}
```

with GDB we set a breakpoint at the return line and run. Now let's look at the following:

```
(gdb) p a
$1 = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
(gdb) p b
$2 = 0x7fffffffe3a0
(gdb) p sizeof(a)
$3 = 36
(gdb) p sizeof(b)
$4 = 0
(gdb) p x
$5 = 36
(gdb) whatis a
type = int [3][3]
(gdb) whatis b
type = int [][]
(gdb)
```

I wonder how this does happen. The C runtime environment assumes that the type of b is `int [3][3]` (because `sizeof(b)` is 36), but GDB does not.

Comment: `gdb` is using the debug information stored in your executable file in compile time. C runtime... guess what? is getting some information in runtime. But in this case it *is* a bit weird, as your array is not truly variable-length, as `m` is known in compile-time.

Comment: There is not "runtime environment" in C. Just some startup code which is inactive while `main` runs.

Comment: @Olaf: depends on the definition of "runtime environment".

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats: If you have a different one than normal programmers, feel free to state it. And please add a reference where the standard states something about such an environment.

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats: Apparently, the GDB 7.7 might have a bug, see updated answer. This still might be plenty of other reasons such as different DWARF format.

Comment: @Olaf: I don't think that I use it differently. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3900802/5767184) for a definition. And, yes, the term "runtime environment" does not occur in the C11 standard. But that's also true for stack, heap.

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats: The reason there is no stack or heap in the standard is exactly the same as there is no runtime in the standard: none is mandatory to implement the language. The standard library is no run-time, simply because is is not required to implement the standard either (yes, there are required headers, but those doe not provide any code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most obvious explanation would be that you have entered into `main`, but apparently have not reached VLA declaration.

To cover this, the C11 (N1570) §6.2.4/7 *Storage durations of objects* states that (emphasis mine):

> For such an object that does have a variable length array type, its
>   lifetime extends **from the declaration** of the object until execution of
>   the program leaves the scope of the declaration.35)

The remedy is to step up into the declaration of VLA (tested  with gcc 4.4.7 and gdb 7.2):

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at so.c:1
1   int main(void){
(gdb) s
2     int a[3][3] = {1};
(gdb) s
3     int m = 3;
(gdb) s
5     int b[m][m];
(gdb) s
6     x = sizeof(b);
(gdb) p b
$5 = {{-1207961984, 0, 1114472}, {6381016, 6319652, -1073745804}, {6416216, 14, 129100401}}
gdb) whatis b
type = int [variable][variable]
```

It may be also a discrepancy between `gdb` versions or some sort of bug, though the latter is always the last thing to consider.

**EDIT:**

I have build gdb 7.7 (CentOS 6.8 32-bit) from [source](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/) and it displays the address of `b` instead of array content, so I confirm that issue is with this specific version and consider it has a potential bug or misfeature.

On the other hand, the latest version 7.11 behaves correctly.

#### `GDB 7.7`

```
[grzegorz@centos workspace]$ gdb-7.7/gdb/gdb -q a.out 
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80483ab: file so.c, line 1.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/grzegorz/workspace/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at so.c:1
1   int main(void){
(gdb) s
2     int a[3][3] = {1};
(gdb) s
3     int m = 3;
(gdb) 
5     int b[m][m];
(gdb) 
6     x = sizeof(b);
(gdb) p b
$1 = 0xbffff0c0
```

#### `GDB 7.11`

```
[grzegorz@centos workspace]$ gdb-7.11/gdb/gdb -q a.out 
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80483ab: file so.c, line 1.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/grzegorz/workspace/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at so.c:1
1   int main(void){
(gdb) s
2     int a[3][3] = {1};
(gdb) 
3     int m = 3;
(gdb) 
5     int b[m][m];
(gdb) 
6     x = sizeof(b);
(gdb) p b
$1 = {{-1207961984, 0, 1114472}, {6381016, 6319652, -1073745676}, {6416216, 14, 129100401}}
```

Moral story: Either upgrade or downgrade your version of `gdb` to get correct behaviour

Comment: The OP states "*with GDB we set a breakpoint at the return line and run*"...Can you show the output of `whatis b` in your run?

Comment: Right. In general, memory for the VLA can't be allocated until execution reaches the declaration, because it can depend on values that haven't been computed until that point. (A compiler is free to do the allocation early and/or with a compile-time computed size if it's able to. In this case, the VLA can be folded into the stack frame for the function call.)

Comment: @Eugene Sh.: Sure. I attached the output and "soften" my answer.

Comment: So we see that GDB knows that it is VLA, but can't tell it's dimensions. Do you get the same output *before* the VLA declaration? I guess you just have a different version of the GDB with the OP..

Comment: What version of GDB do you use?

Comment: @EugeneSh: It still the same, with both variable indices.

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats: It's GNU gdb 7.2. Could you specify yours version in question? It may be a discrepacy between two versions indeed.

Comment: I use GDB 7.7, I did everything exactly as you said. But `p b` still just gives me the *address* of `b`.

Comment: It could be the way it is compiled aswell